# Add new column to database table with migrations fails with - Nothing to migrate

Tags: php, database, laravel, migration, laravel-5.4

I just learned how to use Migrations. I successfully created a table with this schema:

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('units', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Unfortunattely I missed the column `path`, so I've tried to add it. First I informed myselfe in the laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#columns) to learn how to add new columns.

From the documentation:

> The table method on the Schema facade may be used to update existing
>   tables.

**My attempt:**

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('units', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('units', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('path');
    });
}
```

However, after executing `php artisan migrate` I get `Nothing to migrate`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to rollback migration first which will destroy last migration tables with all data:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

And then run `php artisan migrate` command again. It's the best option while app is in development.

If you don't want to do that for some reason (app is live etc), but just want to add a column then create a new migration and add this code:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('units', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('path');
    });
}
```

And run these commands:

```
composer dumpauto
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: Ok but `php artisan migrate:rollback` will remove all already existing data from the table? Correct?

Comment: @EdwardBlack the first option, yes. It will remove all tables from the previous migration. If you do not want that, use the second option.

Comment: Am I correct that the command `php artisan migrate:rollback` will just execute the `down()`Method from the migratation file? If i just execute `echo 'hello';` inside of it and run the rollback command, then It shows me 'hello' inside of the console, so I assume that I am correct.

Comment: @EdwardBlack yes, but it will do this for all migrations in the last batch.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to crate a new migration for your column update. alternatively, you could roll back your last migration, add the missing column, and re-run migration (assuming you have not ran your migration on production)

to roll back: php artisan migrate:rollback